# How can the, encrypted with AES, and BASE64 encoded, SSH private key, have size smaller than specified?

Tags: ssh-keygen, base64

This might be obvious to some, but I wonder, if I generated 8192 key in size with:

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 8192
```

How can the, encrypted with AES, and BASE64 encoded, SSH private key, have size smaller than specified 8192?

It has a size of 6446.

Is there some compression involved?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An 8192 rsa key is **8192 bits**, not bytes. That is 1024 bytes.

Encoding bytes in BASE64 increase its size in a factor of 4/3:

```
$ echo $((1024*8/6))
1365
```

Which is close to the size of the key inside the public key file.

```
$ awk '{print $2}' rsatest.pub | wc -c
1397
```

Of course, the "private key file" [contains (at least)](https://www.gnupg.org/documentation/manuals/gcrypt-devel/RSA-key-parameters.html):

1. the value of m (public modulus)
2. the value of e
3. the value of d
4. the value of p
5. the value of q

And, in fact, it contains 8 (big and small) numbers:

```
cat rsatest | grep -v -- ----- | tr -d '\n' | base64 -d | openssl asn1parse -inform DER
```

That increase the size in a factor of at least 4, it contains 6363 bytes.

Some other way to look inside the private file is:

```
openssl rsa -text -in rsatest
```

Which shows that what the file contains are integers for

- modulus
- publicExponent
- privateExponent
- prime1
- prime2
- exponent1
- exponent2
- coefficient

Comment: `openssl asn1parse` by itself strips PEM(ish) header and trailer and un-base64's by default, but neither it nor your form works for OpenSSL's _encrypted_ 'traditional' (non-PKCS8) privatekey format which is what `ssh-keygen` writes (by default except ed25519) when encrypting as Q stated. For that use `openssl rsa -text` or `openssl pkey -text`.

Answer (score 2):

RSA key lengths are specified in bits, not bytes. Your bit RSA key has a modulus of length 8192 bits, i.e. 1024 bytes.